# Simple auto-updating AJAX page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I am sort of new to AJAX and I am trying to get this to work. What I am trying to do is create a messaging app that automatically updates every 3 seconds.

Here is my script:

```
function first() {
    var searchUser = $("input[name='username']").val();

    $.post("messageSearch.php", {userVal: searchUser}, function(output){
        $('#messageField').html(output);
    });
}

function searchm() {
    var searchUser = $("input[name='username']").val();

    $.post("messageSearch.php", {userVal: searchUser}, function(output){
        $('#messageField').val(output);
    });
}
setInterval( "searchm()", 3000 );
```

Here is my messageSearch.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$userdb = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', '', 'social-network');

if(isset($_POST['userVal'])) {
    $searchm = $_POST['userVal'];
    $output = '';
    if ($searchm == ''){
        echo $output;
        exit();
    }

    $uidquery = mysqli_query($userdb, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$searchm' LIMIT 1");
    $uid= '';

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($uidquery)) {
        $uid = $row2['id'];
    }
    $uid = 2;

    $query = mysqli_query($userdb, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE p2=$uid AND `read`='n' LIMIT 3");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($count == 0) {
        $output = 'You have no messages.';
    } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $from = $row['p1'];
            $message = $row['message'];
            $time = $row['time'];
            $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time));

            $fromResult = mysqli_query($userdb, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$from'");

            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($fromResult)) {
                $fromFirst = $row1['first_name'];
                $fromLast = $row1['last_name'];

                $from = $fromFirst.' '.$fromLast;
            }

            $output .= '
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <div>
            <strong>'.$fromFirst.' '.$fromLast.'</strong>
            <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                <em>'.$time.'</em>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>'.$message.'</div>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="divider"></li>

            ';
        }
        $output .= '<li><a class="text-center" href="#"><strong>See All Messages</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>';
    }
}
echo ($output);
?>
```

For some reason the first load works fine though the second one comes up blank. Hopefully you can help, though thanks in advance.

Comment: First you should check in console that ajax return any result. and second in searchm function you used $('#messageField').val(output);i hope this would be a div. IN jquery DIV does not allowed this as In first function you used html.Let me know if it solve the problem.

Comment: Comes blank? even with error reporting on? `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: your `first` function seems not used, does it ? Also, beware that your code is exposed to SQL Injection Attack, you should definitely correct this point

Comment: All the SQL statements are wrong. You are not concatenating the variables correctly. Do "sql ".$php_val." rest of sql"

Comment: my first() function is being called onLoad of body, though it seems to be that searchm() doesn't work as that is the one that returns no value.

Comment: Also, you should show us those `#messageField` and `input[name='username']` HTML code to be sure there is no other problems (ex: if `input[name='username']` is contained in `#messageField` element), and use JavaScript `console.log` to see what values are sent and what values are retrieved

Comment: So why are you using one time `.html` method, and the other time `.val` method ? They behave differently and `.val` will only work with form elements.

Comment: Rookie error by me. Though I have realised that the problem must be something other than the javascript because each time the messageSearch.php gets sent back after the first it is blank.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval( "searchm()", 3000 );` should be
`setInterval( searchm, 3000 );`

Another error, in your PHP:

```
$query = mysqli_query($userdb, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE p2=$uid AND `read`='n' LIMIT 3")
```

should be:

```
$query = mysqli_query($userdb, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE p2=".$uid." AND `read`='n' LIMIT 3")
```

Lastly

```
$fromResult = mysqli_query($userdb, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$from'");
```

to

```
$fromResult = mysqli_query($userdb, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$from);
```

Comment: Actually, there is no difference.

Comment: I have added that to my page though this hasn't seemed to fix the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: I agree that the latter form is preferred, but both work

Comment: This is true, but I don't think this answer to the question. @HAL9000 this improves *a bit* the performance since there is no "string code evaluation" step done by the browser

Comment: Yeah that is better but it hasn't fixed it and i don't know why someone down voted.